# principal component eigenvectors are not perpendicular to each other

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, eigenvector

I obtained eigenvectors of cluster point clouds using the below code.

```
   for (size_t j = 0; j < cluster_indices.size (); j++){
     static int line=0;
     Eigen::Vector4f centroid;
     Eigen::Matrix3f covariance_matrix;

    // Extract the eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    Eigen::Vector3f eigen_values;
    Eigen::Matrix3f eigen_vectors;

    pcl::compute3DCentroid(*cloud_filtered,cluster_indices[j],centroid);

    // Compute the 3x3 covariance matrix 
    pcl::computeCovarianceMatrix (*cloud_filtered, centroid, covariance_matrix);
    pcl::eigen33 (covariance_matrix, eigen_vectors, eigen_values);
    //~ _viewer->addLine<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (centroid, eigen_vectors, "line");


    std::cout << "centroid:"<<centroid<<std::endl;

    cloud_cluster->points.push_back(centroidToPoints(centroid));  
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++){   

        std::cout << "eigenvector "<<i<<":"<<eigen_vectors.col(i)<<std::endl;
     cloud_cluster->points.push_back(matrixToPoints(eigen_vectors.col(i)));
     _viewer->addLine<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (centroidToPoints(centroid), matrixToPoints(eigen_vectors.col(i)), "line"+line);
     line++;
     }
    }
```

and then i converted the centroid and eigenvectors to points respectively. with the help of below code.

```
pcl::PointXYZRGB centroidToPoints(Eigen::Vector4f& c){
     pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_eigen (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
     cloud_eigen->width  = 15;
     cloud_eigen->height = 1;
     cloud_eigen->points.resize (cloud_eigen->width * cloud_eigen->height);
     cloud_eigen->points[0].x=c[0];
     cloud_eigen->points[0].y=c[1];
     cloud_eigen->points[0].z=c[2];
     //~ pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerGenericField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud_handler2 (cloud_eigen, "z");
    //~ _viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (cloud_eigen, cloud_handler2, "second cloud");
    //~ _viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 2, "second cloud");
 return cloud_eigen->points[0];
```

}

```
pcl::PointXYZRGB EigenToPoints(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3> >::ColXpr ev){

  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_eigen (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
     cloud_eigen->width  = 15;
     cloud_eigen->height = 1;
     cloud_eigen->points.resize (cloud_eigen->width * cloud_eigen->height);
     cloud_eigen->points[0].x=ev[0];
     cloud_eigen->points[0].y=ev[1];
     cloud_eigen->points[0].z=ev[2];

 return cloud_eigen->points[0];
```

}

But the eigenvectors are not perpendicular.as shown below(green and red dots are eigen vectors).[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?.

Comment: They look perpendicular to me... what are the components of the eigenvectors? Just to make sure they absolutely aren't perpendicular.

Comment: compute the inner product `(v_i, v_j)` and see if it's zero for `i != j`. If it is zero, they are perpendicular.

Comment: @wolfPack88 - rectangular plane :                                                 eigenvector 0:(0.0464242,0.649373,0.759051)
eigenvector 1:(-0.99191,-0.059905,0.111915)
eigenvector 2:(0.118146,-0.758107,0.641339)

Comment: Since its a 2d photo you can see it as perpendicular.But its not.

Comment: @manjunathreddya04: The eigenvectors are all mutually orthogonal. Do a dot product on them yourself to see; they all come out to something on the order of 10^(-7), which is easily explained by rounding error.

Comment: But when i draw the line from the centroid, the angles are not 90 degrees with each other.

Comment: @wolfPack88 any idea how to find the width of those objects using eigenvectors

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "draw the line from the centroid", but the dot product of eigenvector `i` with eigenvector `j`, provided `i != j` is 0. Therefore, they are orthogonal. Unfortunately, I don't know what you mean by "find the width of the objects using eigenvectors" either. Do you mean the length of the object along an eigenvector?

Comment: yes,length of an object along eigen vector

Comment: if you see the figures above there is a blue rect object.i wanna find the dimensions of it using eigenvectors

Comment: In that case, the easiest method is to just use the eigenvectors you have to rotate your coordinate system to be in the principal frame of reference. At that point, the length of the object along the eigenvectors is a simple matter of "max value of x_i - min value of x_i", where x_i represents x, y, and z.